# I want to measure time passed between action in the code

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to measure time in miliseconds, that this line took:

```
before=datetime.datetime.now()  
response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com")
after=datetime.datetime.now()
```

It is supposed to be kind of workaround for server, which doesn't ping back, so I have to measure it from the server response.
I can get the string back string **0:00:00.034225** if I deduct two times and I am able to grab miliseconds as a substring, but I would like to get miliseconds in some cleaner way (whole difference in ms, including time converted from seconds, if the server responds with really big delay).

Comment: You won't get to the third line until the second line has finished, at which point either the default timeout in `urlopen` has been hit or the server has responded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`after - before` is a `datetime.timedelta` object whose `total_seconds` method will give you what you are looking for. You can find additional information [in the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

You will just have to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds. Don't worry, although the method is called `total_seconds`, it includes milliseconds as decimal places. Sample output:

```
>>> d = t1 - t0
>>> d.total_seconds()
2.429001
```

This won't give you a timeout though, only a mesurement of the duration.

Comment: Glad to help; feel free to accept (or accept an alternate answer) if your issue it solved.

Answer (score 1):

`urlopen` allows you to pass a timeout parameter, and will automatically abort after that much time has elapsed. [From the docs:](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2#urllib2.urlopen)

> ```
>  urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
> ```
>
> The optional `timeout` parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
>   global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works
>   for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections.

---

Python actually has a mechanism for timing small pieces of code -- `timeit.Timer` -- but that's for performance profiling and testing, not for implementing your own timeouts.